# Delete the content of a string between a word and special character in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string like this -

```
['name' {d763e18f-1719-480b-bcd6-8fea7bad894e} Parameter, 'class' {8471633e-4a54-4c86-bd2b-56d58baf2fbb} Parameter, 'id' {23471633e-4a54-4c86-bd2b-56d58baf2fbb} Parameter]
```

And I want the following result -

```
['name' , 'class' , 'id']
```

All the content between the word in quotes `''` and `,` should be deleted.

How do I achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to match:

```
('\w+'\s*).*?(?=[,\]])
```

And replace with `$1`

regex in java would be `('\\w+'\\s*).*?(?=[,\\]])`

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fD6tO4/3)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex.

```
('\w+'\s*).*?(?=[,\]])
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("'.+?'").matcher(str);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while(m.find()) {
    if (sb.length() > 0) {
        sb.append(',');
    }
    sb.append(m.group());
}
String res = sb.toString();
```